# React Native + Firebase 9, cant use off() with reference to unsubscribe from onValue changes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expo

Firebase 9,real time database / react native with expo.

**issue**: I can not unsubscribe from firebase RTD onChange event listener.

The docs say: "Calling off() on a parent listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes; off() must also be called on any child listeners to remove the callback."
[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

**error**: When I try using `.off` on the reference I get `reference.off() is not a function`

```js
const db = getDatabase();
const reference = ref(db, "users/" + props.userId);

const updateScore = (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.val() !== null) setHighScore(highscore);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (props.userId === "") props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
  else onValue(reference, updateScore);
  
  // throws error reference.off() is not a function
  return () => reference.off();
}, [props.userId]);
```

I've also tried `reference.unsubscribe()` and `reference.removeEventListener(updateScore)` with no luck. They both trigger the same error `reference.**** is not a function`.

Without clearing up this event listener I have a memory leak in my application.

Comment: As a side note for a better user experience, make sure that wherever `userId` is coming from, that you've handled the brief moment where `currentUser` can be `null` while Firebase Auth validates the session. You may find that you get navigated to login when you've already logged in if this isn't handled properly. Also consider passing the current page with the navigation call so the user is returned to the current page once they've finished logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For v9, when you call `onValue` it returns an unsubscribe function, as shown in the [reference docs for `onValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue). So to unsubscribe:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.userId === "") props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
  else return onValue(reference, updateScore);
}, [props.userId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To unsubscribe simply use:
`off(reference, "value");`
here `reference` is the reference of the document from firebase.
i.e `const reference = ref(db, "users/" + props.userId);`