# React Native memory leak error after updating to Firebase version 9 onValue

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going through to update my code for the Firebase version 9 modular form. I am now using onValue. From what I'm reading it returns a function that removes the listener. But I'm still not doing it right because although it functions well at first, when I change the database on the backend with the app open I get the "can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component" error when I'm in a different app screen. See old and new code below please.

OLD CODE:

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadListings();
},[]);

const loadListings = async () => {  
  setLoading(true);
  updateInput('');
  let testData = [];
  let searchData = [];
  db.ref('deals').once('value', (snapshot) =>{
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
      testData.push({
        id: child.key,
        title: child.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? child.val().title : 'NA',
      })
      searchData.push(
        child.val().title
      )
    }) 
  })
  .then(()=>{
    checkMessages(testData);
    setLoading(false);
  })
  .catch((error) => Sentry.Native.captureException('Error MessagesScreen function loadListings 1 ' + error));
}
```

NEW CODE:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadListings();
  },[]);

const loadListings = async () => {  
  setLoading(true);
  updateInput(''); 
  const dbRef = ref(db, 'deals');
  return onValue(dbRef , (snapshot) => {
    let testData = [];
    let searchData = [];
    let storeData = filterStores;
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
      testData.push({
        id: childSnapshot.key,
        title: childSnapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? childSnapshot.val().title : 'NA',
      })
    }) 
    checkMessages(testData);
    setLoading(false);
  })
}
```

After receiving answer below I changed the useEffect to this instead and now it works:

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback( () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        // You can await here
        const response = await loadListings();
        // ...
        return () => response();
      }
      fetchData();
    }, [])
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned the [unsubscribe function returned from `onValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue). In order to call it, I think you'll want to grab it from the invocation and then call it on some navigation state change.

Assuming you're using React Navigation, it might look something like this (using the [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook)

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function YourComponent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(async () => {
      const unsubscribe = await loadListings();

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [])
  );

  const loadListings = async () => {  
    setLoading(true);
    updateInput(''); 
    const dbRef = ref(db, 'deals');
    return onValue(dbRef , (snapshot) => {
      let testData = [];
      let searchData = [];
      let storeData = filterStores;
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
        testData.push({
          id: childSnapshot.key,
          title: childSnapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('title') ? childSnapshot.val().title : 'NA',
        })
      }) 
      checkMessages(testData);
      setLoading(false);
    })
  } 

  return <View />;
}
```

Also don't forget to either use `async/await` for your asynchronous `loadListings` function, or use `.then()`. Otherwise you'll be working with an unresolved promise.

I also found a [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238794/react-native-firebase-9-cant-use-off-with-reference-to-unsubscribe-from-onv) that helped me get to this answer. Maybe that'll be of some use to you.

Comment: Thank you so much I edited my question to include the changes I made after your help and it seems to be working well, the errors are gone. When you say "dont forget to use async/await" are you referring to this line: const response = await loadListings(); or saying that I additionally need to put an await or then elsewhere?

Comment: Happy to help! And yes I was referring to `const response = await loadListings();`, I should have been clearer. Just wanted to call that out because it's easy to miss.